# Linear functionals and dual bases with matrices

Tags: real-analysis

Let $M_{2 \times 2}$ denote $2 \times 2$ matrices. I am given that all linear functionals over 
$M_{2 \times 2}$ are determined by a matrix $B \in M_{2 \times 2}$ and written as
$\psi (x) = \text{Tr} (B' A)$ for all $A \in M_{2 \times 2}$, where Tr denotes trace of a matrix. How can I show that
the basis $T= \{ T_{11}, T_{12}, T_{21}, T_{22} \}$ of $M_{2 \times 2}$ is self dual, in the sense that
"the dual basis is the same basis as $T$"? $T_{ij}$ here denotes the $2 \times 2$ matrix with $0$ in every entry except in the entry $ij$, which has entry $1$.

I tried comparing traces of various products to see if they are the same and tried to find a basis $T^{\ast} = \{ T_{1} ^{\ast}, T_{2} ^{\ast}, T_{3} ^{\ast} , T_4 ^{\ast}\}$ such that the product of these elements with the elements in $T$ give $0$ or $1$ as in the definition of Kronecker delta, but struggled in both attempts to show that the elements are actually the same. (Is there a different approach to this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\ T_{11}^*, T_{12}^*, T_{21}^*, T_{11}^*\ $ be the basis dual to $\ T_{11}, T_{12}, T_{21}, T_{11}\ $. Then, by definition,
$$
\text{Tr}\left({T_{ij}^*}'\sum_{s=1}^2\sum_{t=1}^2 x_{st}T_{st}\right)= x_{ij}
$$
for all matrices $\ x_{ij}\ $ of scalars. But
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}\left({T_{ij}^*}'\sum_{s=1}^2\sum_{t=1}^2 x_{st}T_{st}\right)&=\sum_{u=1}^2\sum_{v=1}^2\left(T_{ij}^*\right)_{vu}\sum_{s=1}^2\sum_{t=1}^2 x_{st}\left(T_{st}\right)_{vu}\\
&=\sum_{u=1}^2\sum_{v=1}^2\left(T_{ij}^*\right)_{vu}x_{vu}\ .
\end{align}
So, now choosing $\ x_{uv}=\delta_{su}\delta_{tv}\ $, we must have
\begin{align}
\delta_{si}\delta_{tj}&=\sum_{u=1}^2\sum_{v=1}^2\left(T_{ij}^*\right)_{vu}\delta_{su}\delta_{tv}\\
&=\left(T_{ij}^*\right)_{st}\\
&=\left(T_{ij}\right)_{st}\
\end{align}
for all $\ i,j,s,t\in\{1,2\}\ $. That is, $\ T_{ij}^*=T_{ij}\ $.